# Android - how to use getId() to access orientation specific layout sub views

Tags: java, android, exception, orientation

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // get orientation
    LinearLayout layout = isLandscape()
            ? (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.main_layout_l)
            : (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.main_layout_p);
    Log.i("info", "layout is " + layout.getId());
    start();
    run();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Log.e("On Config Change",
            (newConfig.orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                    ? "LANDSCAPE" : "PORTRAIT");

    // added -- this fixes the background not showing 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

I have two layouts (two files, layout/activity_main.xml, layout-land/activity.xml) for both orientations. 
What is to be displayed is slightly different depending on the orientation
ie: portrait won't have some extra panels and some stuff has to be moved around.
I need to access the view programmatically.

When accessing 'layout' I get a NullPointerException

each layout orientation has different ids ending in "_p" or "_l" in the xml file to differentiate whether portrait or landscape, when accessing them in java.

Both xml files are currently LinearLayout->TextView
Either way I cant get them to draw

I am using a thread and a clock to handle the drawing calls. Like in a game. 
This is needed for doing some various custom animations.

I don't even think the background is drawing.

If I change from LinearLayout and call the TextView directly by its id 
it runs without error, but nothing draws.

Comment: When you rotate the screen, was the activity recreated? Or does it call onconfigurationchanged hook? It sounds your activity didn't load the correct activity.xml

Comment: onConfigurationChanged see above. android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" is also set

Comment: ok added "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);" to onConfigurationChanged() now the background draws, but no text or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `android:configChanges` attribute.

It'd be better not to use `android:configChanges` attribute.

Please refer to Android Developers Site in details

`Caution: Handling the configuration change yourself can make it much more difficult to 
use alternative resources, because the system does not automatically apply them for you. This technique should be considered a last resort when you must avoid restarts due to a configuration change and is not recommended for most applications.`

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes

Comment: they were set but not for this activity

Comment: If this attribute is not set, `onConfigurationChanged()` method in `activitiy' should not be called when changing orientation.

Comment: I checked the log messages and it is not. I still don't have any text or anything else showing up on the screen.